# Swift JSON Array of items

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode6

Hi guys i have a problem. I'm using JSON in swift to getting information about a user, so the response is :

```
{
  "user_details": {
    "name":"samsun",
    "email_id":"charchit2@ymail.com",
    "mobile":"9503322593",
    "phone":"NA",
    "phone_os":"NA",
    "devicetoken":"",
    "city":"Mumbai",
    "state":"Maharashtra",
    "DOB":"0000-00-00",
    "gender":"Female",
    "address":"Shanti apts, A105",
    "pinCode":"400068",
    "isRegistered":"verified",
    "imei":"" 
  },
  "vehicles": {
    "1": {
      "vechicle_no":"MH03AW0001",
      "model_no":"Alto 800",
      "variant":"LXI",
      "color":"White",
      "date_of_purchase":"10/10/2014",
      "insurance_company_name":"Bajaj",
      "insurance_expiry_date":"10/10/2015",
      "created_at":"2015-06-02 23:31:30",
      "fuelType":"CNG",
      "vinNumber":"HSJHFJ10" 
    },
    "2": {
      "vechicle_no":"MH48S8403",
      "model_no":"Swift",
      "variant":"VXI",
      "color":"AZURA GREY",
      "date_of_purchase":"17/10/2007",
      "insurance_company_name":"NEW INDIA",
      "insurance_expiry_date":"17/10/2007",
      "created_at":"2015-06-27 22:22:57",
      "fuelType":"Petrol",
      "vinNumber":"ABCD0316"
    }
  },
  "status":"1",
  "verified":"true"
}
```

ok now i need to save the vehicle number ( vehicle_no ) but because there are different user i need to save like the first vehicle number, the second vehicle number, the third vehicle number exc.. So for example this user has two vehicle number and i can see it because there is the second vehicle number after the "2". So how can i get both vehicle number ? i need to be able to read also the third, fourth exc.. vehicle number if a user has this. Sorry if I have not explained it well but thank you in advance.

This is my jSON Code right now.

```
 func MyVehicleInfo() {

    let Mobile = save.stringForKey("USERNAME")!

    let post:NSString = "mobile=9503322593"

    NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://saimobileapp.com/services/sai_authenticate.php")!

    let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)
    println(urlData)
    if ( urlData != nil ) {
        let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);
        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            var error: NSError?

            let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary




            let vehiclenodb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["1"]! as! NSDictionary)["vechicle_no"]! as! String
            let modelnodb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["1"]! as! NSDictionary)["model_no"]! as! String
            let variantdb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["1"]! as! NSDictionary)["variant"]! as! String
            let colordb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["1"]! as! NSDictionary)["color"]! as! String
            let datepurchasedb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["1"]! as! NSDictionary)["date_of_purchase"]! as! String
            let insurancecompanynamedb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["1"]! as! NSDictionary)["insurance_company_name"]! as! String
            let insuranceexpirydatedb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["1"]! as! NSDictionary)["insurance_expiry_date"]! as! String
            let fueltypedb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["1"]! as! NSDictionary)["fuelType"]! as! String
            //var emaildb = ((jsonData as NSDictionary)["user_details"] as! NSDictionary) ["email_id"] as! String



            var vehicleno:Void = save.setObject(vehiclenodb, forKey: "VehicleNumberSave")
            var modelno:Void = save.setObject(modelnodb, forKey: "ModelNumberSave")
            var variant:Void = save.setObject(variantdb, forKey: "VariantSave")
            var color:Void = save.setObject(colordb, forKey: "ColorSave")
            var datepurchase:Void = save.setObject(datepurchasedb, forKey: "DateofPurchaseSave")
            var insurancecompanyname:Void = save.setObject(insurancecompanynamedb, forKey: "InsuranceCompanySave")
            var insuranceexpirydate:Void = save.setObject(insuranceexpirydatedb, forKey: "InsuranceExpirySave")
            var fueltype:Void = save.setObject(fueltypedb, forKey: "FuelTypeSave")

            save.synchronize()





        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Where is the "array" you mention in your title??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is some ugly JSON you have to deal with. You can extract the vehicles like this.

```
if let vehicles = jsonData["vehicles"] as? NSDictionary {
   let vehiclesKeys = vehicles.allKeys
   for key in vehiclesKeys {
     println(vehicles[key])
   }
}
```

Comment: Xcode changed the vehicles.allKeys() in vehicles.allKeys it is ok ?

Comment: i have also an error on println line that say `cannot find an overload for println that accepts an argument list of type (AnyObject?)`

Comment: Yeah, it is completely fine. :)

Comment: You are not supposed to leave the print line, inside of the for loop you can iterate on every vehicle and perform your saving operations. You can access the current vehicle by using  ``if let vehicle = vehicles[key] as? NSDictionary { // save here }``

Comment: use of unresolved identifier 'vehicles' and use of unresolved identifier 'key'